# How to separate a list of strings with specific characters

Tags: macos, bash, shell-script

for example, I have a list:

aa bb cc dd ee

I hope to get
"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"

Is there any way to do that with shell scripts?

Comment: What operating system? What scripting language?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's mac with bash. I just got one solution: sed 's/\ /","/g filename. but this does not add " at the beginning and end of the line

Comment: Please [edit] and add that information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with your solution (comment):

> I just got one solution: `sed 's/\ /","/g filename`. but this does not add `"` at the beginning and end of the line

To match the beginning or the end of the line, use `^` or `$` respectively. There are [few ways to do several consecutive substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97428/108618). In your case it may be:

```
sed 's/\ /","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/' filename
```